# Return initial value or most recent occurance with XPath then run operator

Tags: xml, xpath, infopath

I have the following XPath 1.0 expression in MS InfoPath (I will post accompanying XML):

`//my:Value_Modifier_Group[1=count(following-sibling::my:Value_Modifier_Group)]//my:Modified_Start_Value[(text())] | //my:Start_Value[text() and not(//my:Value_Modifier_Group[1=count(following-sibling::my:Value_Modifier_Group)]//my:Modified_Start_Value[(text()])]`

If there is an initial value and no "Modified Value" yet then the initial value is returned. If a modified value is present then it is returned.

I need to return that value and then perform the following operations on it:

`number(//my:Value_Modifier_Group[1=count(following-sibling::my:Value_Modifier_Group)]//my:Modfied_Start_Value) + number(//my:Value_Modifier_Group[0=count(following-sibling::my:Value_Modifier_Group)]//my:Start_Value_Increase) - number(//my:Value_Modifier_Group[0=count(following-sibling::my:Value_Modifier_Group)]//my:Start_Value_Decrease)`

This operation adds or subtracts an increase/decrease value. The problem is that this expression returns a NaN if no `Modified_Start_Value` is present. Works great otherwise.

I need to team both of these expressions together into a single XPath expression.

- If `Modified_Start_Value` has a preceding value, use that in operations
- If `Modified_Start_Value` does not have a preceding value then use `Start_Value` in operations instead
- It is important that I always use the "preceding" value because the preceding value is fixed. It acts as a reference point or starting point.

Here is a sample of the XML I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?mso-infoPathSolution solutionVersion="1.0.0.2" productVersion="14.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="file:///C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\Chris\Local%20Settings\Application%20Data\Microsoft\InfoPath\Designer3\ef41a19775b4ce0\manifest.xsf" ?><?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.3"?>
<my:myFields xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-09-19T13:28:35" xml:lang="en-us">
<my:Start_Value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">6</my:Start_Value>
<my:Main_Group>
    <my:Value_Modifier_Group>
        <my:Modified_Start_Value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">6</my:Modified_Start_Value>
        <my:Start_Value_Increase>0</my:Start_Value_Increase>
        <my:Start_Value_Decrease>0</my:Start_Value_Decrease>
    </my:Value_Modifier_Group>
<my:Value_Modifier_Group>
    <my:Modified_Start_Value>6</my:Modified_Start_Value>
    <my:Start_Value_Increase>0</my:Start_Value_Increase>
    <my:Start_Value_Decrease>0</my:Start_Value_Decrease>
</my:Value_Modifier_Group></my:Main_Group>
</my:myFields>
```

I hope this question isn't too hastily put together! Busy day today...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I am going to self answer this question as I just figured it out.

The key is to combine the XPath expressions by placing the value from the first expression into a node and then referencing that node in the second expression.

It seems that the pipe command | does not play well with other operators.

The following expression returns values in the following way:

- `//my:Value_Modifier_Group[1=count(following-sibling::my:Value_Modifier_Group)]//my:Modified_Start_Value[(text())] | //my:Start_Value[text() and not(//my:Value_Modifier_Group[1=count(following-sibling::my:Value_Modifier_Group)]//my:Modified_Start_Value[(text()])]`
- If no preceding `Modified_Start_Value` is available before the first `Modified_Start_Value` node the expressions defaults to the initial value.
- In this way you are guaranteed the most recent valid `Start_Value` or `Modified_Start_Value`

This value of this expression is then put into a node titled `StartVModStart`. The XPath for this node is then put into the evaluating expression:

`../../../my:StartVModStart + number(/descendant-or-self::node()/my:Value_Modifier_Group[0 = count(following-sibling::my:Value_Modifier_Group)]//my:Start_Value_Increase) - number(/descendant-or-self::node()/my:Value_Modifier_Group[0 = count(following-sibling::my:Value_Modifier_Group)]//my:Start_Value_Decrease)`

- This expression uses "the most recent" value and then adds or subtracts the changes

In this way one can keep a "running sum" through the course of document, starting in an initial node and moving all the way through repeating nodes.

This question seems highly convoluted, so forgive me if both my question and answer do not seem clear. As I reach for more complex functionality the required XPath expressions become more and more complex.

Comment: "It seems that the pipe command | does not play well" Do you mean under | a boolean logical "or" operand? I believe that in Infopath XPath [one cannot use "|", "&" but only "or", "and' in lower case](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/23630/81980.aspx#81980)

Comment: What I experienced (in MS InfoPath) is that when a | is put into an expression that also has a + or - the whole thing seems to go haywire. It's more than likely that I don't know what I'm doing (that seems to be the most common cause of my problems lately...) but after splitting my initial expression into two expressions and storing the value of the first expression in a node, the problem went away.